# the best one for learning on -- I'm exactly not sure what "learning on" means here

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Getting Started with Arduino, 3rd Edition by Massimo Banzi and Michael Shiloh (2015)](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029267.do)

Example:

> There are many versions of this board; the one we’ll use throughout this book is the Arduino Uno, which is the simplest one to use and the best one for **learning on**.

*to learn on*, I would reckon, typically means to continue learning something, but from the context of this passage and the fact that it has only been a few pages of the book since I started reading it, it doesn't really sound like what they mean is that the Arduino microcontroller board is the best one for continuing your learning process.

Comment: "learning on" indicates something you are using in the learning process, in this example the Arduino Uno. *on* refers to the object, not to a time reference

Comment: There is a bucking bronco and a gentle mare. If you don't know how to ride a horse, which one is better to learn on?  "He learned how to program *on* a DEC PDP-11".

Comment: @TRomano DEC PDP-11, now that's a blast from the past!

Comment: @Peter Enjoy the stroll down memory lane :)

Comment: "learn on" mean "with which to learn".  In this case, "on" is a short form of "upon".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Learning on"* here refers to the Arduino board as the instrumentality of learning.

> At the moment, I am using the Arduino board to learn on (I'm learning on the Arduino board).